# Sendability of function types in instance method 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)' does not match requirement in protocol 'URLSessionProtocol'

Tags: swift

I am getting below warning while writing URLSessionProtocol.
What could be the reason?

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    typealias DataTaskResult = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

    func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTask
}

extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple change it to

```
typealias DataTaskResult = @Sendable (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
```